# @ObservedObject with property initializer - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this code:

```
struct TestView: View {

    lazy var currentCompetitionID: String

    @ObservedObject var fetchSingleCompetitionData = FetchSingleCompetitionData(option: "\(currentCompetitionID)")

    var body: some View {
       Text("\(fetchSingleCompetitionData.competitionList.name)")
    }
}
```

I receive the error: "Cannot use instance member 'currentCompetitionID' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"

Is there any way to initialize and use variable in the same view?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetchSingleCompetitionData` is being initialized as part of `init`. Lazy vars are only available afterwards.
Consider moving the initialization to a fully-qualified initializer.